How to get Poco using cmake and conan2
I'm newby in using cmake and conan2, so I need help with Poco library. I've installed conan2, wrote a simple conanfile.txt and installed all the libs I need. But now one of them (ncurses) works just fine and I can't figure out how to make Poco to work as well.
conanfile.txt:
[requires]
poco/1.11.3
ncurses/6.5

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

[layout]
cmake_layout

And CMakeLists.txt in src dir:
find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation Crypto CONFIG)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Poco::Poco)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CURSES_LIBRARIES} 
    Poco::Foudation Poco::Poco)

I can't figure out how to make it works search doesn't help much...
Search stackoverflow, github, tried to use recipe from conan website and to use FetchContent (it works that way).

You have forgot to describe what is the problem. "I can't figure out how to make Poco to work as well" is not description of the problem. What is the error? Copy paste logs of configuration process and if this passed then copy paste logs from build process. We should see what is an actual error. For first glance at file you have included everything looks fine.
